# Find pattern and remove it from all files

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, scripting, perl

Please help me solving following problem. Remove all pairs of characters `\` `n` from Test_Macro in all files. Please see below example:

Fil1.txt

```
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string",
       "test string2 \n");
// Some code or text

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

dir1/File2.txt

```
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string",
       "test string2 \n",
        123456);
// Some code or text

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

Expected Result:

File1.txt

```
Test_Macro(abc, def, " string1 string2 test string",
   "test string2 ");
// Some code or text

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

dir1/File2.txt

```
Test_Macro(abc, def, " string1 string2  test string",
   "test string2 ",
    123456);
// Some code or text

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. I am planning to write some script. Because I have many different types of files and many such macros. Thanks in advance!

The arguments to Test_Macro can have nested calls to other macros, and may have any characters inside strings.

Comment: I did something very similar once for saving Lisp programs out of the Read-Eval-Print-Loop output of CLisp, wherein I have to look for nested parentheses and pull out the matching end paren correctly; [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34283441/5419599).

Comment: @Sundeep: My final goal is to remove all \n from Test_Macro() in all files.

Comment: @Sundeep: I have updated my final output for both these files.

Comment: if you are okay with perl solution, try `grep -rlZ 'Test_Macro' | xargs -0 perl -0777 -i -pe 's/(Test_Macro\(.*?\))/$1 =~ s|\\n||gr/ges'` ... use some test files though before applying it on actual files

Comment: Thanks Sundeep. I am fine with perl solution. I tried but it gives some error. `Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/(Test_Macro\(.*?\))/$1 =~ s/\"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/(Test_Macro\(.*?\))/$1 =~ s/\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors. `

Comment: The perl shouldn't give you an error. Did you notice that the character after `=~ s` is a vertical bar or pipe symbol, and not a forward slash? However the solution suffers from not handling nested parentheses. The perl regular expression `Test_Macro\(.*?\)` matches from `Test_Macro(` to the FIRST `)`, not the matching one. This makes a difference if the code is `Test_Macro((1_1),"delete this \n")`.

Comment: Yes. I used pipe ( | ) only. Anyways I understood what you are trying to say. This works only if there is no nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File1:

```
$ sed '/Test_Macro/{N;$!N;s/.*\(Test_Macro[^)]*);\).*/\1/;p;};d' abc.txt
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string",
       "test string2 \n");
Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
```

File2:

```
$ sed '/Test_Macro/{N;$!N;s/.*\(Test_Macro[^)]*);\).*/\1/;p;};d' abc2.txt
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string",
       "test string2 \n",
        123456);
Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
```

ps, the easiest way to remove all line breaks is;

```
echo -e "line \n break" | tr "\n" " "
```

without line breaks;

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/[^;]\n[ ]*/ /g;' abc2.txt  | grep Test_Macro
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string" "test string2 \n" 123456);
Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
```

without "\n" but with line breaks... lol

```
$ sed '/Test_Macro/{N;$!N;s/[ ]*\\n//g;s/.*\(Test_Macro[^)]*);\).*/\1/;p;};d' abc2.txt
Test_Macro(abc, def, " string1 string2 test string",
       "test string2",
        123456);
Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
```

just removing "\n" string (and trailing space);

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\\n[ ]*//g;' abc2.txt
Test_Macro(abc, def, "string1 string2 test string",
       "test string2 ",
        123456);
// Some code or text

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

once again (hopefully the last time)... removing string "\n" when in the function Test_Macro, but not outside, and not removing line breaks;

```
$ sed '{N;/Test_Ma/{s/[ ]*\\n//g;};s/\(Test_Macro[^)]*);\)/\1/};' abc2.txt
Test_Macro(abc, def, " string1 string2 test string",
       "test string2",
        123456);
// Some code or text \n

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

update;

```
$ sed '{:a;N;/Test_Ma/{s/[ ]*\\n//g;};ta};' abc2.txt 
Test_Macro(abc, def, " string1 string2 test string",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
       "test string2",
        123456);
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n
// Some code or text \n

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
```

Comment: This is not working. It gives an error like "Command not found"

Comment: did you copy paste the $ by any chance?

Comment: Thanks mike. Can you tell me how can I combine this two commands? I actually want to remove all "\n" from these Test_Macros.

Comment: Thanks again mike. I think you misunderstood me. Please see my expected output in the question. I just want to remove all "\n" characters from these macros. Don't want to remove line breaks.

Comment: removing all pairs of `backslash` and `n` can be done with `sed 's/\\n//g'`.

Comment: Exactly. I just want to remove this after matching some pattern.

Comment: And there I was thinking that your problem was how to match something more complicated than a pattern! sed takes patterns, so `sed '/pattern/s/\\n//'`, maybe with a trailing `g` to make it global or a number to replace the nth match. Let me get on with thinking up a parser for your problem.

Comment: i added an update with "without "\n" but with line breaks... lol"

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikejonesey and icarus:  This worked perfectly fine. I think I need to practice more examples using "sed". Your second last change will only print this macro from the file. I also want to print rest of the code as it is. Also, your last change will remove all "\n" from that file..lol I only want to touch Test_Macro and remove "\n" from this macro. It seems I need to combine some sed commands.

Comment: Please point out some good sed tutorials.

Comment: another example added, (just remove "\n" string but only within the function), I added a \n in the src file on a comment line as an example.

Comment: re: tutorials, nothing beats the man pages and experimenting, but o'reilly's sed n awk combo is good. Also one of my fave books ever is "Mastering unix shell scripting", available on amazon, is a wiley book.

Comment: Thanks @mikejonesey. Appreciate all your help and time. This worked completely fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47547/discussion-between-ronme026-and-mikejonesey).

Comment: Glad you have an answer. If it works for you then fine, but there are a lot of cases where it will do the wrong thing.

Comment: hopefully last time.. This didn't work if there are more than 2 lines. I just realized that, in few files, if that macro has 6-7 lines, I can still see "\n" after 2 lines. I am still trying to understand this commands. I think second part (in your last changes) should perform the first action till end of parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

There is a phrase that should be remembered, "regular expressions can't count".

This matters in this case because a lot of 'simple' unix tools are based on regular expressions. The counting here is counting the open and close parentheses ('round brackets') that might be used inside the arguments to Test_Macro.

If the calls to Test_Macro *never* have nested parentheses, then there is an easy trick. First change every `)` character to a newline, and vice versa. Then delete every line which doesn't contain Test_Macro, and remove everything up to the Test_Macro. At this point a part of the processed File2.txt would look like this

```
Test_Macro(abc, def, " string1 string2 test string",)   "test string2 ",)    123456
```

So now we need to convert the `)` back. At this point you have a couple of options. I favor using sed to get rid of the extra spaces at the same time. We also need to add back in the `)` and maybe the `;`

Putting this together, we have

```
find . -type f | while read -r fn
do
   < "$fn" tr ')\n' '\n)' | sed -n 's/.*Test_Macro(/Test_Macro(/p' | \
     sed 's/) */ /g;s/$/);/'
done
```

If there is the possibility that the arguments to Test_Macro includes nested parentheses then you need to bring out significantly bigger guns, as you need to parse the input rather than just pattern match it. (In theory if you can restrict the nesting level then you can pattern match but in practice this gets very very complicated very quickly and you should discount this approach). There are parser frameworks for languages like python, or you can build tools on top of tools like lex.

Comment: Thanks icarus. Unfortunately I have lot of macros with nested parentheses. Btw thanks for your prompt help and reply.

Comment: OK. In that case, because regular expressions can't count, we need more powerful tools and the solution will not fit inside this comment. What do you have available? C compiler?, lex or flex?, python?, lua?, something else?

Comment: I have C/C++ compiler, python, perl. I also have lex & flex. But not familiar with it.

Comment: Having read all the comments and the edited original post, my solution here is for a different problem. I was attempting to remove everything from the file except the macro calls and then get the macro calls onto a single line. It appears that what @ronme026 wants is to remove all pairs of backslash and `n` characters that occur within the arguments of Test_Macro. We knew this requires us to parse the data.

Comment: Yes. I only want to touch that macro and remove all occurrences of "\n". I don't want to change anything else. I am sorry if I haven't explained my problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answer was prepared before the question was revised.  The original form of the question included:

> When I tried to find some pattern using "grep", it only prints first line. But I want till end of the bracket.

### Regular expressions can't count, but Sed can loop.

Here is a Sed snippet that will grab from any line containing `Test_Macro` to the line with the appropriate close paren, **even if there are nested parentheses:**

```
#n
/Test_Macro/{
  p;
  :rep
  s/([^()]*)//;
  trep
  /^[^(]*$/d;
  h;
  n;
  p;
  x;
  G;
  brep
}
```

Converted to a one-liner, this looks like so:

```
sed -n -e '/Test_Macro/{p;:rep' -e 's/([^()]*)//;trep' -e '/^[^(]*$/d;h;n;p;x;G;brep' -e '}'
```

Input and output look like so:

```
$ cat temp 
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string",
       "test string2 \n");
// Some code or text

Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
// Some code...
$ sed -n -e '/Test_Macro/{p;:rep' -e 's/([^()]*)//;trep' -e '/^[^(]*$/d;h;n;p;x;G;brep' -e '}' temp 
Test_Macro(abc, def, "\n string1 string2 \n test string",
       "test string2 \n");
Test_Macro(asdsadas, "test String1");
$
```

Comment: Yes, once you add conditional jumps you have a Universal Computing machine (assuming no line length limits), so we can parse. My gut is saying that extending the code in sed is going to become too complicated, although I would not object to sed being a target language for a translation from something simpler to read.

Comment: @icarus, my favorite explanation of Sed (from a comment somewhere on this site, in fact, modified slightly) is: Sed is the assembly language of text processing, Awk is the command line spreadsheet, and Perl is everything else you can imagine.  :)

Comment: I like it, can I steal it?

Comment: @icarus, sure.  I stole it myself.  :)  You can give attribution to "someone on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange" like I did; drive more traffic to the site (maybe).  ;)